# two different AsyncTask methods are waiting for each other

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I don't know how to tell the problem.

I have two AsyncTask methods. doAreYouStanding and StartTimeout, when I'm running both in MainActivity

if StartTimeout in if I wait 10 seconds, the other method is waiting.

Why is this startTimeout thread pausing my other method?

doAreYouStanding in doInBackground works after waiting onPreExecute for 10 seconds

```
    new doPopup().execute((Void) null);
    // new StartTimeout().execute((Void) null);




    private class doAreYouStanding extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.e("YHACKUP", "onPreExecute");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Object... objects) {
            Log.e("YHACKUP", "doInBackground");
            return null;
        }
    }


    private class StartTimeout extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            if (!(ActivitySplash.this).isFinishing()) {
                layout_timeout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Object... objects) {
//            try {
//                Thread.sleep(10000);
//            } catch (Exception e) {
//            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I'm sorry if my english is bad

Answer (score 0):

By default async tasks run serially. so Intil, the first asyncTask gets completed, second asyntask will not be started. In order to run paelelly, use executeOnExecutor method

```
 new doPopup().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```